# Search for file and retrieve it's path in VB

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to search for a file `"prince.exe"`, and retrieve it's file path using VB.Net but I cant find a method of doing this. I figured you might be able to use the command prompt but I'm not sure how.

```
Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Search for file and retrive path'
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to google - vb.net find file in directory

Comment: What I'm guessing you're looking for is `OpenFileDialog`.  You should be able to stumble across multiple examples of how to utilize this with a simple google search.

Comment: No that's not what I'm trying in to do I'm trying to search the computer for this file and get its path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) function of System.IO.Directory.  Make sure to use the overload that lets you pass the SearchOption value of AllDirectories.

```
Dim strStartingDirectory As String = "C:\YourStarting\Directory\"
Dim lstMatches As List(of string) = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strStartingDirectory, _
                                                                 "prince.exe", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()
```

Comment: I didnt realize that Stackoverflow was a code writing service.

Comment: Is there any way to do this for the whole computer and not just a perticular drive?